# Как получить результат перевода в Delphi из Google Translate?

Tags: delphi, google-translate

Как стринговую переменную Text перевести в Goolge Переводчике и вернуть (получить) перевод в программу (допустим в тот же Text).

Сложности именно на получении перевода. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

[Google translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

---

прошу обратить внимание на вкладку **Pricing**